# Static Referencing over multiple classes

Tags: java, static

In short, I'm trying to learn how to use more classes, getters and setters, and using static correctly. With this, I decided to make chess.

```
package Package;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

public class Game {
    private static Color whiteSqaure = new Color(255, 248, 241);
    private static Color whitePiece = new Color(250,230,230);
    private static Color blackSquare = new Color(131, 127, 127);
    private static Color blackPiece = new Color(20,3,3);

    private static Font font = new Font("DialogInput",Font.BOLD,48);

    private static JFrame f = new JFrame();
    private static JPanel grid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 8, 0, 0));
    private static JButton[][] b = new JButton[8][8];

    static Piece[] whitePawns = new Pawn[8];
    static Piece[] whiteRooks = new Rook[2];
    static Piece[] whiteKnights = new Knight[2];
    static Piece[] whiteBishops = new Bishop[2];
    static Piece[] whiteQueen = new Queen[1];
    static Piece[] whiteKing = new King[1];
    static Piece[] blackPawns = new Pawn[8];
    static Piece[] blackRook = new Rook[2];
    static Piece[] blackKnight = new Knight[2];
    static Piece[] blackBishop = new Bishop[2];
    static Piece[] blackQueen = new Queen[1];
    static Piece[] blackKing = new King[1];

    private static void colorButtons() {. . .} 


    private static void addPiecesToBoard() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            //String test = "♙";
            String test = Pawn.getWhitePieceIcon();
            b[6][i].setText(test);
        }
    }


    private static void finishFrame() {
        f.add(grid);
        f.pack();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(900, 900);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        colorButtons();
        addPiecesToBoard();
        finishFrame();
    }
}
```

> Main class

```
package Package;

abstract class Piece {

    private String pieceName;
    private String whitePieceIcon, blackPieceIcon;


    Piece(String pieceName, String whitePieceIcon, String blackPieceIcon) {
        this.pieceName = pieceName;
        this.whitePieceIcon = whitePieceIcon;
        this.blackPieceIcon = blackPieceIcon;
    }


    String getWhitePieceIcon() {
        return whitePieceIcon;
    }
    public void setWhitePieceIcon(String whitePieceIcon) {
        this.whitePieceIcon = whitePieceIcon;
    }
    public String getBlackPieceIcon() {
        return blackPieceIcon;
    }
    public void setBlackPieceIcon(String blackPieceIcon) {
        this.blackPieceIcon = blackPieceIcon;
    }
    public String getPieceName() {
        return pieceName;
    }
    public void setPieceName(String pieceName) {
        this.pieceName = pieceName;
    }
}
```

> Piece class

```
package Package;

class Pawn extends Piece {
    Pawn() {
        super("Pawn", "♙", "\u265F");
    }
}

class Knight extends Piece {
    Knight() {
        super("Knight", "\u2658", "\u265E");
    }
}

class Bishop extends Piece {
    Bishop() {
        super("Bishop", "\u2657", "\u265D");
    }
}

class Rook extends Piece {
    Rook() {
        super("Rook", "\u2656", "\u265C");
    }
}

class King extends Piece {
    King() {
        super("King", "\u2654", "\u265A");
    }
}

class Queen extends Piece {
    Queen() {
        super("Queen", "\u2655", "\u265B");
    }
}
```

Then my classes for all chess pieces

now, I am trying to set the text of my JButton to Unicode, which I can do easily, but I cannot do with through my getter because I'm having issues with my static vs. Non-static. I know that this can be done all in static methods, but I want to learn how to make THIS, so please don't reply saying that this method isn't effective.

I know my issue is in the class Game, in the method `addPiecesToBoard()`, at the getter. I'm just unsure of how to fix it

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you want most everything static?

Comment: Welcome to SO. 1. "I know that this can be done all in static methods"  this is rarely a good idea. 2. You should not post so much code and information for a question which boils down to how to use a setter. It make it more difficult  to help. Please post [mcve]

Comment: Responding to Dave - I have the methods static in my "Main class"(Game) because it's really just an extension of my main method.

In better words, I don't know a better way to use static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so lets first take a look at the line

`static Piece[] whitePawns = new Pawn[8];`

what you really want is:

`static Piece[] whitePawns = new Pawn[]{new Pawn(), new Pawn(), new Pawn(), ...};`

which creates 8 instances of a pawn object, the first creates a array full of null objects.

This array is 8 instances of a pawn object. a pawn object as you have defined it can call all the methods that you have declared in the abstract class `Piece`. these methods can only be called on a instance of the class `Pawn` when you invoked it as `Pawn.getWhitePieceIcon()` you are calling it statically meaning it is does not need a intatiated object of `Pawn` to exist inorder for it to be called. So in this instance you want to be calling that function on the instances of pawns that you have created like so:

```
private static void addPiecesToBoard() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        //String test = "♙";
        String test = whitePawns[i].getWhitePieceIcon();
        b[6][i].setText(test);
    }
}
```

similarly the board is declared wrong its a double array of null `JButton`s, you have to instantiate them.

```
private static JButton[][] b = createBoard();

private static JButton[][] createBoard() {
    JButton[][] b = new JButton[8][8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            b[i][j] = new JButton();
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

i have got it to run, but unsure of your desired result, hope this helps.

Comment: In my colorMainPanels I have a for loop initializing my JButtons (b[i] = new JButton), but I didn't have that for my pieces, thanks. But that doesn't allow me to used the other 2 classes because of the static vs non-static

Comment: And whitePawns[i], sorry didn't see that. It worked for me. I appreciate it.